# Basement Mold Issues

Tags: moisture

thank you for the fantastic resources on this forum!

I am interested in a house that has a significant amount of mold on the drywall in the basement. I thought initially it was from flooding; however, there lines of mold growth start and stop in perfect lines and at different heights (see photo).  Has anyone seen something like this before?  Any idea what this might be from?
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in buying this house. If so, do you think it would be a good idea to go ahead and get a mold remediation expert out there to not only help identify the cause (they've probably seen this before)  but give you a quote on fixing it so that the seller negotiates the price down?

Comment: It does not look like mold. Try to scrape it

Comment: I'd wait for the survey to come back before doing any other investigation. That's the entire idea of the survey. They will also have access to general knowledge about the area, water table etc. Pointless owning a dog if you're going to bark yourself ;) It may be from earlier remedial work.

Comment: @Tetsujin Where did the OP say he was getting a survey and what does that have to do with the discoloration on his walls? Where did the OP mention owning a dog?

Comment: @RetiredATC - 1) Who buys a house without having a survey done? 2) it's a metaphor old as Noah. There's no point in having something that can do a given task, if you are going to ignore it & do the task yourself, ie have a dog & bark yourself.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I take from this that you are surveying an old barky dog named Noah.   I hope it works out.   For both of you.

Comment: We know mold needs moisture, first and very important find out where it came from as you cannot solve the problem without eliminating the moisture problem.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this exact pattern in a house I helped renovate. The previous owners had put carpet on the walls (don't ask me why). I guess the carpet absorbed moisture from the basement or maybe the people shampooed it but when I removed it, the wall was covered in surface mold. There were quite a few layers of paint on the wall so we were able to remove the mold without replacing the wall. You'll want to have it checked out before committing to buy because it could be a major problem.

Comment: Thought it was flooding at first, but do not know any flood that leaves different heights on walls.  Carpet or something does fit better.

Answer (score 0):

When I lived in Ohio I remodeled a basement that had this exact problem. What I found is the Sheetrock had been replaced at different times or different heights.

There was a seam at the mold line below that was 1 sheet that had sucked or wicked the water up possibly earlier repairs were cut out and the new sheet put in but this was on the 4 exterior walls. At first it did not make sense to me but when I cut the old out I went a few inches above the mold line and it broke off at the seam/ mold on each above the seam was dry and no mold. You may have the same issue and the water only had to be a few inches deep to wick up several feet.